# bootstrap dropdown menu items size not changing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have one more problem with bootstrap navbar dropdowns

this is my code

```
<header class="navbar navbar-purple navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://pos.shalvasoft.tk/"><span class="first">ShalvaSoft</span> <span class="second">POS</span></a>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown langs">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span id="selectedlang"> <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-ge'></i></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="hidden"><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ge"><i class='flag-icon flag-icon-ge'></i></a></li><li><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ru"><i class='flag-icon flag-icon-ru'></i></a></li><li><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="en"><i class='flag-icon flag-icon-us'></i></a></li>                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown langs"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><img src="http://pos.shalvasoft.tk/public/image/users/1_thumb.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"> <span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"><li><a href="http://pos.shalvasoft.tk/logout">logout</a></li></ul></li>            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

now in the css I have this rulers

```
.navbar-purple .navbar-nav > li:not(.langs) .dropdown-menu{width:118px !important;}
.navbar-purple .navbar-nav > li:not(.langs) .dropdown-menu > li{width:118px !important;}
.navbar-purple .navbar-nav > li.langs .dropdown-menu{min-width:63px !important;}
.navbar-purple .navbar-nav > li.langs .dropdown-menu > li{width:63px !important;}
```

As you see I need to add on clas langs and it`s childs 63px width
and on others I need to add default size or 118px.
but this code not working
see the images

here you can see how is displaying langs class

[image: langs class]

and here is the other dropdown

[image: other dropdown]

what can I do to change **:not(.langs)** width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obvious because your dropdown with logout button has that 'langs' class

```
<li class="dropdown langs">
```

Remove it would solve the problem.